# hard functional equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

For positive integer $n$ , let  $U_{n}=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} | z^{n}=1\}$ , for which value values of $n$ , there exist an application $f : U_{n} \to U_{n}$ such that :

$f \circ f(z)=z^{2} $

I have been stuck on this for about two weeks right now , is hard for me to describe how such function works , my idea was : from the obivious fact that $\{f^{k}(z)| k\in \mathbb{N} , k\geq 2 \}$ generate at least $n+1$ roots to $X^{n}-1$ which lead us to a contradiction , but failed , any help or suggestion would be very welcome , thank you .

Comment: On which domain should $f(f(z)) =z^2$? If its just $U_n$ then $f$ is just a finite Permutation and seems "easy". I even think $f(z) =z^2$ works (dont have a lot of time now ;) )

Comment: This might be a partial solution. Suppose that f has the form $z↦z^k$ for an integer k. Then f⚪f is just $z↦z^｛k^2｝$. Thus if $k^2=2 mod n$ has a solution, such an f exists.

Comment: Never mind the $f(z) =z^2$...

Comment: Note that $f$ is not a permutation because it is not injective, at least for even $n$.

Comment: For example, for prime number n which is congruent to plus minus 1 mod 8 (7, 17, ...), such an f exists.

Comment: No such function exists if $n$ is a multiple of $4$, or if $2$ is a primitive root modulo $n$.

Comment: @QingZhang  , let $w=\exp(i\frac{2\pi}{n})$ for $p \in [[0,n-1]]$ $z=w^{p}$  there existe  $k(z)\in [[0,n-1]]$ such that $f(z)=w^{k(z)}$  then $f\circ f(z) =w^{k(f(z))}=z^{2}=w^{2p}$  then $k(f(z))=2p [n]$  how did you find $k^{2}=2[n]$ ? thank you